# I want to filter rows by the content of their cells, with multiple words

Tags: r, filter, rows

I have a table with this look 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAaYS.png)

I want to filter all the rows that in the column Cellular have the word membrane.
But when I do this I get only the rows that have the word membrane alone, and not any other word.
Help

Comment: FYI, I presume this got voted down because it is not a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it includes a screenshot instead of text data, and it's also a question that has surely been answered many times before.

Comment: Show the code you tried so we can help you fix it

Comment: I tried        Base3<-Base[grep("membrana", Base$Cellular ),]   But I got an empty table.

Comment: Got it right with       Base3<-Base[grepl("membrane", Base$Cellular, ignore.case=TRUE),] THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regular expression with the `grepl()` expression:

```
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:4, Cellular = c("membrane", "membrane", "cytoplasm", "cellsurface;membrane"))

dat[grepl("membrane", dat$Cellular),]

#   id             Cellular
# 1  1             membrane
# 2  2             membrane
# 4  4 cellsurface;membrane
```